# Keras prediction

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, keras, prediction

I have been editing this stock price prediction program. I am new to python programming. I am trying to print the predicted values for the next 10 days. however it is printing the prediction for the 1st day only .

````
start = "2003-01-01"
end = "2018-01-01"

hist.get_stock_data("AAPL", start_date=start, end_date=end)
process = DataProcessing("stock_prices.csv", 0.9)
process.gen_test(10)
process.gen_train(10)

X_train = process.X_train.reshape((3379, 10, 1)) / 200
Y_train = process.Y_train / 200

X_test = process.X_test.reshape(359, 10, 1) / 200
Y_test = process.Y_test / 200

model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(20, input_shape=(10, 1), return_sequences=True))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(20))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation=tf.nn.relu))

model.compile(optimizer="adam", loss="mean_squared_error")

model.fit(X_train, Y_train, epochs=10)

print(model.evaluate(X_test, Y_test))

data = pdr.get_data_yahoo("AAPL", "2017-12-19", "2018-01-03")
stock = data["Adj Close"]
X_predict = np.array(stock).reshape((1, 10, 1)) / 200
print(model.predict(X_predict)*200)
```
````